# How can I retrieve the contents of a HTML text box from PHP in response to a button click?

Tags: php, html

What is the best way to put a text box on the following HTML page and then, *without reloading the page*, get its content in PHP when the user clicks the button?

```
<?php require_once "phpuploader/include_phpuploader.php" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Simple File Upload - use SaveDirectory property</title>
    <link href="demo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="demo">
        <h2>Attach some files</h2>
        <p>Attach some files using the button below.</p>
        <ul>
            <li>Allowed file types is set to: jpg, gif, png, zip 
                       - multiple files (Max 10M)</li>
        </ul>

        <?php
            $uploader=new PhpUploader();

            $uploader->MultipleFilesUpload=true;
            $uploader->InsertText="Upload Now";

            $uploader->MaxSizeKB=10240;
            $uploader->AllowedFileExtensions="jpeg,jpg,gif,png,zip";

            $uploader->SaveDirectory="savefiles";

            $uploader->Render();
        ?>          
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I know I can use form and Post but I want to stay on the same page.

Comment: look for ajax if you need something server-sided, otherwise javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically if you make the form post to itself, you will stay on the same page. That aside, your only solution is AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I used PHP, but I'm guessing your going to need AJAX if you want to avoid a full on postback.

The following link might help you out:

http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_ajax_database.asp

Answer (score 0):

Well the simplest answer is just to submit to the same page:

```
<form action=""></form>
```

If you do this and add your form processing code at the top of the PHP file, you can submit, process the POST variable, but stay on the same page too.